# htaccess redirection from a url to another url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect the following url:

`http://abc.com/colleges/first.php`

to

`http://abc.com/first.php`

using `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess`

How do I do this?

Comment: search for [.htaccess redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.htaccess+redirect)

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39063 before voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

use 301 redirection 
example : redirect 301 /old/old.htm http://www.you.com/new.htm

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the `first.php` page then:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^colleges/first.php$ /first.php
```

If it's every page in the `/colleges` folder that needs to be redirected to the root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^colleges/(.*)$ /$1
```